# How can I console.log the 2nd part of the message after the command

Tags: discord.js

Im making a command called -note, which would send a note to console for me to look at. I can't seem to figure out how to split the 2nd part after the command and then log it to console. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy:

```js
let msg = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
console.log(msg);
```